# Join on a view T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, view, sql-server-2014

I'm making a view. What i now have is:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwEventDetails]
AS
SELECT 
    ISNULL(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EventID), 999999999) AS Row,
    STUFF(DetectorID, len(DetectorID), 1, '0') as SiteID,
    DetectorID AS DetectorID,
    StartedOn AS StartedOn,
    EndedOn AS EndedON,
    EventDescription AS EventDescription,
    EventCategoryID AS EventCategoryID,
    EventSeverityLevelID AS EventSeverityLevelID,
    EventStatusID AS EventStatusID,
    Processed AS Processed,
    CASE WHEN EndedOn IS NOT NULL
        THEN
            DATEDIFF(SECOND, StartedOn, EndedOn)/ 3600.0
        ELSE 
            DATEDIFF(SECOND, StartedOn, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)/ 3600.0
    END
        AS Duration

FROM Event

GO
```

The result that i'm getting from this view is:
[image: View Result]

The result i'm getting is correct. However, i need 1 more value which is not in the **Event** table. And i dont know how to get this value.

The view is based on the **Event** table. which looks like this:

[image: Event Table]

Now in this table there is a row called **DetectorID**.
**DetectorID** leads to the table: **Detector**:

[image: Detector Table]

In this table, you'll see a row named **TrackID**.
**TrackID** leads to the table **Track**:

[image: Track Table]

In the table there is a row named **TrackName**.
This is the value that i want in the view.
Is there a way to achieve this?

So basically a short summary.
Is there a way to go from:

> Event -> Detector -> Track

via a view which is based on **Event**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joining to other tables is a fairly standard thing in sql.

You can use an `inner join` to only return rows where there is a matching `Detector` and `Track`, or you could use `left join` when there may not be matching values in the corresponding tables.

Also, `row_number()` will not return `null`, no reason to wrap that in `isnull()`.

```
--create view dbo.vwEventDetails as
select 
    row_number() over (order by e.EventId) as Row
  , stuff(DetectorId, len(e.DetectorId), 1, '0') as SiteId
  , e.DetectorId
  , e.StartedO
  , e.EndedOn
  , e.EventDescription
  , e.EventCategoryId
  , e.EventSeverityLevelId
  , e.EventStatusId
  , e.Processed
  , case when e.EndedOn is not null
        then datediff(second, e.StartedOn, e.EndedOn)/ 3600.0
      else datediff(second, e.StartedOn, current_timestamp)/ 3600.0
      end as Duration
  , t.TrackId
  , t.FromName
  , t.ToName
  , t.TrackName
from Event e
  inner join Detector d
    on e.DetectorId = d.DetectorId
  inner join Track t
    on d.TrackId = t.TrackId
```

Comment: Thank you, This is working!  I don't know a lot about Joins, and did not know how to do a join on multiple tables. And also in a view. But thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with two join statements:

```
...
FROM Event
JOIN Detector ON Event.DetectorID = Detector.DetectorID
JOIN Track ON Detector.DetectorID = Track.TrackID
```

Then add `Track.TrackName` to the end of the select fields

(you'll have to add `Event.` before your other fields where there are columns with the same names)